# Как получить/распарсить элемент для .click()?

Tags: c#, anglesharp, cefsharp

Типо нашел [тут](https://kostyly.ru/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-csquery-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/) метод под название .click. Мне нужно кликнуть на кнопку на [этом](https://kad.arbitr.ru/) сайте кнопку "Найти", такую, синюю.
Но как этот элемент-то получить в программе?!
Еще заметил что если в норм браузере открывать, то нету такого меню, которое появляется при CefSharp

[image: Фото из программы]

(Сами зайдите в браузере и посмотрите что такого нет.)

Использую - CefSharp
Парсер - CsQuery/AngleSharp

Comment: Так найдите этот элемент в инспекторе обычного браузера, и составьте xpath/css запрос. На каком этапе у вас проблема?

Comment: @aepot Ну вот я не знаю как это сделать...

Comment: выполнить яваскрипт [document.querySelector('ваш селектор')](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).click();